# A non-linear regression model for within subject observations

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, nonlinear-regression

I am trying to perform the equivalent of a repeated-measures ANOVA using data that have a non-linear relationship. There are two independent variables: Spacing between stimulus (10, 20, 35, 45, 60), and the number of the stimulus (3-6). The trials are presented in the same block in random order (e.g., trial1 -> 6 stimulus with spacing 20, trial2 -> 4 stimulus with spacing 45, trial3-> 3 stimulus with spacing 60 etc.).   What I want to know is the extent the performance is affected by these two variables.

I checked this post: [Equivalent to ANOVA for non-linear (quadratic) relationships](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321403/equivalent-to-anova-for-non-linear-quadratic-relationships)

Basically, they did a multilevel modelling letting the intercept and coefficients vary by individuals.

Now my question is, can I do the same analysis **separately** for each level of the 2nd IV (ie, the number of stimulus). Or is it not correct to treat the the levels of the 2nd IV separately? To illustrate what I mean, here is an example:

[image]

Comment: I would fit a GAMM. See, e.g., [this paper](https://peerj.com/preprints/27320/) for an introduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could indeed specify a quadratic relationship between performance and spacing that is different per stimulus, and test for these differences. For example, you could use something like the R code below, based on **lme4**:

```
library("lmerTest")
fm <- lmer(performance ~ poly(spacing, 2) * stimulus + (poly(spacing, 2) | subject),
           data = <your_data>)
anova(fm)
```

This fits a linear mixed model for performance with a quadratic effect for spacing and interaction with stimulus, and random intercepts, and linear and quadratic random slopes. The p-values from the `anova()` function are based on the Satterthwaite's method for the denominator degrees of freedom.